# C# BackgroundWorker ReportProgress Behaving Strangely

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

My `backgroundWorker` uses `ReportProgress` to update the `ProgressPercentage` of a long process.  What happens is in two out of three entries into `ProgressChanged` `ProgressPercentage` is zero, whereas every third entry into `ProgressChanged` the `ProgressPercentage` is what I would expect.  This happens like clockwork; it is very repeatable.  Here is some simplified code demonstrating my setup (to reduce the length, I've removed the error-handling code):

```
AutoResetEvent areProgressChanged = new AutoResetEvent(false);

  private void backgroundWorkerProgram_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
  {
     bool bRetVal = true;
     int iRetries = 3;
     int iProgress = 0;

     // Repeat Program message and entire sequence until programming
     // is complete or Retries reaches 0...
     do
     {
        bRetVal = Program();

        this.eBgwProgramStatus = BgwProgramStatus.BUSY;
        bRetVal = this.WaitForReceive(SHORT_ACK_WAIT, backgroundWorkerProgram);

        switch (this.eCommsRsp)
        {
           case CommsRsp.ACK:
              this.eBgwProgramStatus = BgwProgramStatus.BUSY;
              iRetries = 3;
              break;
        }
     }
     while ((!backgroundWorkerProgram.CancellationPending)
        && (!bRetVal) && (iRetries > 0));

     // Repeat Write and Data message until programming is complete...
     do
     {
        this.eBgwProgramStatus = BgwProgramStatus.BUSY;
        bRetVal = Write();

        this.eBgwProgramStatus = BgwProgramStatus.BUSY;
        bRetVal = this.WaitForReceive(SHORT_ACK_WAIT, backgroundWorkerProgram);

        switch (this.eCommsRsp)
        {
           case CommsRsp.ACK:
              this.eBgwProgramStatus = BgwProgramStatus.BUSY;
              bRetVal = SendData(pData_c);
              break;

           default:
           case CommsRsp.NACK:
           case CommsRsp.NONE:
              this.eBgwProgramStatus = BgwProgramStatus.NO_ACK_RXD;
              iRetries--;
              bRetVal = false;
              break;
        }

        this.eBgwProgramStatus = BgwProgramStatus.BUSY;
        bRetVal = this.WaitForReceive(SHORT_ACK_WAIT, backgroundWorkerProgram);

        switch (this.eCommsRsp)
        {
           case CommsRsp.ACK:
              this.eBgwProgramStatus = BgwProgramStatus.BUSY;
              iProgress = (this.iProgramSize * 100) / PIC32.ProgMem.Length;
              this.backgroundWorkerProgram.ReportProgress(iProgress);
              this.areProgressChanged.WaitOne();
              iRetries = 3;
              this.iRow++;
              break;

           default:
           case CommsRsp.NACK:
           case CommsRsp.NONE:
              this.eBgwProgramStatus = BgwProgramStatus.NO_ACK_RXD;
              iRetries--;
              bRetVal = false;
              break;
        }
     }
     while ((!backgroundWorkerProgram.CancellationPending)
        && (iRetries > 0)
        && ((!bRetVal) || (this.eBgwProgramStatus == BgwProgramStatus.BUSY)));
  }

  private void backgroundWorkerProgram_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
  {
     string sProgressPercentage = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";

     // Report progress.
     this.labelPercentComplete.Visible = true;
     this.labelPercentComplete.Text = sProgressPercentage;
     this.toolStripStatusLabel.Text = this.sProgramming + sProgressPercentage;
     this.textBoxData.AppendText(this.tBusText.ToString());
     this.textBoxStatus.AppendText(this.tStatusText.ToString());
     this.tBusText.Remove(0, this.tBusText.Length);
     this.tStatusText.Remove(0, this.tStatusText.Length);
     this.areProgressChanged.Set();
  }
```

(My apologies for the length, but it was requested.)  The same behavior is exhibitted with and without the `AutoResetEvent`.  Does anyone have any thoughts as to why this may be happenning?  Thanks.

*ADDITIONAL DETAILS*

If I set a breakpoint on `this.backgroundWorkerProgram.ReportProgress(iProgress);`, I can see that `iProgress` increments as expected (slowly, over several intervale, e.g. 0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,etc.).  Then, if I move the breakpoin to `string sProgressPercentage = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";`, the value of `e.ProgressPercentage` does not match the passed value of `iProgress`.  What I get is like 0,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,3,0,0,etc.

Comment: Instead of pseudo-code, why not give us a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem? That will make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: This is not the normal behaviour for a Bgw, so there must be something in your (real) code causing it. So I agree with Jon: post a small demonstrating program. Most likely you will find the problem along the way.

Comment: Have you stepped through this code in the debugger? It looks like you're only calling `ReportProgress` under very specific conditions. Also the value you pass to this method (`iProgress`) is the result of a calculation: `(this.iProgramSize * 100) / PIC32.ProgMem.Length`, whatever that is. It's unclear to me as an outsider what would make you so sure that this value wouldn't be zero sometimes.

Comment: `PIC32.ProgMem.Length` is a fixed value at this point in the application; that is, it can only be changed by user-intervention, and the releated user-controls are disabled while this code is running.  `iProgramSize` increments from zero to `PIC32.ProgMem.Length` as the sequence progresses.  I'm thinking of doing a quick-fix with a global variable.  I know, it's not pretty, but this is holding up more important things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this problem was somehow introduced while optimizing the application for scalability. I finally got the program to a "stable" point again, retested, and the problem has gone away just as mysteriously as it appeared.

Answer (score 1):

What are the first few values of iProgramSize and PIC32.ProgMem.Length ?

For example if PIC32.ProgramMem.Length was 300, and iProgramSize was 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc, then the percentages complete should be 0,0,1,1,1,2  etc.

Also, are you sure the ProgressPercentage is passed incorrectly, could be it that the label control not be updated/refreshed correctly?

Comment: `iProgramSize` starts out as 0 and increments to `PIC32.ProgramMem.Length`, which is a fixed value in this part of the application of about 512K.
If I set a breakpoint on `this.backgroundWorkerProgram.ReportProgress(iProgress);`, I can see that `iProgress` increments as expected (slowly, over several intervale, e.g. 0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,etc.).  Then, if I move the breakpoin to `string sProgressPercentage = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";`, the value of `e.ProgressPercentage` does not match the passed value of `iProgress`.  What I get is like 0,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,3,0,0,etc.

Comment: Strange. I assume the e.ProgressPercentage ends with values like 98,0,0,99,0,0,100 and presumably a workaround would be not to update the labels if e.ProgressPercentage is zero.

Is the number of incorrect values (zeros) related to the number of repeated inputs, ie if you change your iProgress to be = (this.iProgramSize * 50) / PIC32.ProgMem.Length does this mean you end up with more zeros between the correct values?

Comment: Apparently, this problem was somehow introduced while optimizing the application for scalability. I finally got the program to a "stable" point again, retested, and the problem has gone away just as mysteriously as it appeared. I've up-voted your response because you gave my query some critical thought, tried to help, and didn't just dismiss it. Kudos!